# Can't manage line breaks in pdf document generation

Tags: laravel-8, wkhtmltopdf, laravel-snappy

I can't handle the line break in the pdf.

I am generating a PDF created through laravel snappy and having problems with line breaks. in these images, I show you some examples.

**Screenshots**

Breaks starting

[image]

Breaks in the middle

[image]

So, I've tried creating the class:

```
.div-training {
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
    break-inside:avoid !important;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid !important;   
}
```

#### blade-code:

```
<div class="col-8 col-md-8 div-capacitacion">
    <h5>Tablas dinamicas</h5>
    <p><small class="text-secondary">Nota: 96%</small>
    </p>
    <p><small class="text-secondary">Fecha término:
            mar-2022</small></p>
    <p><small class="text-secondary">Industria: Mecánica</small>
    </p>
</div>
```

I've added the 'div-capacitacion' in the div where I need it not to be cut in the middle.

But the result at sight has no effect, since it still makes the cut in the middle, at the beginning, of the div capacitacion.

My expected results should be: set the `div-capacitacion` or wherever that contains the break-inside in the div container of training and when these contents couldn't show completely take the page break and put it inside the next page.

I'm using laravel version 8 and Laravel Snappy package. Laravel snappy uses wkhtmltopdf.